# How to serialize a list of string as a list of objectid

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection *User* mapped with a class like this :

```
class User
{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

The Id property is the identifier of the document; it is represented by a string in C#, but is an objectid in mongo. The following mapping allow to ensure this :

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<User>(cm =>
{
  cm.MapIdProperty(x => x.Id)
    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
    .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
  ...
}
```

I have another collection named Book; each book can be written by one or many authors.

```
class Book
{
  public String Id { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public IList<String> Authors { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

The Id property is identical to this of the User collection. And I want that the each author to be stored in mongo as objectid instead of string : but I do not know how to do that : i do not want to define the serializer of the autors property, but of each element of this property.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Book>(cm =>
{
  cm.MapIdProperty(x => x.Id)
    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId))
    .SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
  // The instruction below is not good and fails, because it maps the collection,
  // not each element of the collection....
  cm.MapMember(x => x.Authors)
    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: these tests were performed using MongoDB.Driver 2.4.3

I was able to accomplish that using the serializer `EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`.

In your case it would be something like:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Book>(cm =>
{
  (...)

  cm.MapMember(x => x.Authors)
    .SetSerializer(
      new EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer<IList<string>, string>(
        new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId)));
}
```

However, the code above will generate a document similar to:

```
{
   _id: "...",
   Title: "...",
   Authors: {
     _t: "List`1"
     _v: [ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...)] 
   }
}
```

---

By changing the `Book.Authors` from `IList` to `List`and by having the following serializer configured:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Book>(cm =>
{
  (...)

  cm.MapMember(x => x.Authors)
    .SetSerializer(
      new EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer<List<string>, string>(
        new StringSerializer(BsonType.ObjectId)));
}
```

I end up with the following object:

```
{
   _id: "...",
   Title: "...",
   Authors: [ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...)]
}
```